# Jest gives "Your test suite must contain at least one test" when certain file is imported even though there is a valid test

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Whenever I import a certain file from my test file, Jest produces an error that I do not have any tests in the test file, even though there is one with just constants that should pass.

This is running inside a create-react-app folder, but I am using a global install of Jest for the server-side testing.

**The Error**

```
FAIL  server/__tests__/server.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Your test suite must contain at least one test.

      at onResult (../../../../usr/lib/node_modules/jest/node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:173:18)
```

A simplified version of the **test file**:

```js
const timer = require("./timer.js");

test("should pass", () => {
  expect(1 + 2).toBe(3);
});
```

A simplified version of **timer.js**:

```js
class Timer {
  constructor(ms, onCompleteFunction) {
    this.ms = ms;
    this.startTime = Date.now();

    setTimeout(onCompleteFunction, ms);
  }
}

test = () => {
  let timer = new Timer(5000, () => console.log("Test Done!"));
};
test();

module.exports = Timer;
```

Answer (score 0):

(This is a self-answer)

Before adding real testing with Jest, in the Timer.js file I had added a quick test function, just to verify that it was working without running the whole app.

Unfortunately, the function, named `test`, was not prefixed with `var`, `let`, or `const`. From what I can tell, it overrode the test function from the Jest library, and this error message was the result. When `test = 1` or similar was present, the error was

```
TypeError: test is not a function
```

This is an extreme edge case due to poor coding practices and something I would have thought was a syntax error on my part, so I don't fault the error message for being unhelpful. I hope this can help someone in the future anyways.